# Recursivity and multithread collisions in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, locking, python-multithreading

Good afternoon

I am trying to modify my recursive function to a multithreaded recursive function to reduce process time.

I have implemented a RLock object on where it was necessary.

My recursive function must prints a nested array with 98 lines but using multithreading sometimes there are collisions and I am not retrieving all nodes.

(With it is works with the synchronous method)

I have tried to reproduce the behavior of my code:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.nodes = []
        self.lock = threading.RLock()

class Git(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.lock = threading.RLock()

git = Git()

def getChildrenFiles(node):
    with node.lock:
        with git.lock:
            # sending some commandes to git repository and get some files
            pass
        myRecursiveFunction(child, False)

def myRecursiveFunction(foo, async=True):
    with foo.lock:
        # (Simulation) Retrieving Foo children name from local files
        foo.nodes.append(Foo(....))

        if not foo.nodes:
            return 

        pool = ThreadPool(os.cpu_count())
        if async:
            results = []
            for fooChildren in foo.nodes:
                results.append(pool.apply_async(getChildrenFiles, (fooChildren,)))

            all(res.get() for res in results)
        else:
            for fooChildren in foo.nodes:
                pool.apply(getChildrenFiles, (fooChildren,))

        pool.close()
        pool.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    foo = Foo("MyProject")
    myRecursiveFunction(foo)

    '''print foo as Tree Like :

    Foo-A
        Foo-B
            Foo-C
        Foo-E
            Foo-K

     '''
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found the problem, it iss very specific to my program but I will still try to explain it.

## Explanation

In the function *getChildrenFiles* I am using a lock for the git object and the git object is declared as a global variable.

The problem was that I am sending some command like:

```
def getChildrenFiles(node):
with node.lock:
    with git.lock:
        sendCommand(....)

    .....

    with git.lock:
        sendOtherCommand(....)

    myRecursiveFunction(child, False)
```

And between  the first command and the second one, an other thread has locked the git object and some files used by the git object in the first thread were changed in the other thread. Then an custom exception was raised.